# What is the fastest algorithm to order list of three values?

Tags: java, algorithm

```
public class Sort {

    enum Sides {
        left, middle, right
    };

    public static void main(String[] param) {
        Sides[] list = { Sides.middle, Sides.right, Sides.left, Sides.middle, Sides.left };

        order(list);
        System.out.print("Ordered: ");
        for (Sides side : list) {
            System.out.print(side.toString() + ", ");
        }
    }

    public static void order(Sides[] sides) {
        //toDo
    }
}
```

Arrays.sort(); isn't the solution here. I know that there is a faster way achived algorithmically.

**Current output:** Ordered: middle, right, left, middle, left,

**Ordered Output:** Ordered: left, left, middle, middle, right,

Values range is fixed

Comment: All sorts are *algorithmic*, so saying that "there is a faster way achieved algorithmically" is meaningless. When you say "order list of three types", it would appear that you mean 3 *values*, because they all have the same type (`Sides`).

Comment: @Andreas I think his terminology made sense ... he's asking for a solution with a better asymptotic runtime complexity (hence "algorithmically faster") as opposed to one that simply performs better in benchmarks (for a small value of N, using a well optimized Arrays.sort() could very well be faster than a poorly implemented radix sort).

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan The terminology would make sense if OP said, "I know that there is *another* algorithm that is faster", but the way it's phrased, OP is implying that `Arrays.sort()` is not an algorithmic implementation, which it is, and that was my point.

Comment: @Andreas Title should be better now.

Comment: This is the [Dutch National Flag problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem) and there is a simple linear solution.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Good comment. Look for java code: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem#Java

Comment: @user3374117: I don't write Java and couldn't provide a Java answer. The C++ solution on that Rosetta Code page though is mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option that doesn't involve changing the enum (this is actually a [Counting Sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)):

```
public class Sort {

    enum Sides {
        left, middle, right
    }

    public static void main(String[] param) {
        Sides[] list = {Sides.middle, Sides.right, Sides.left, Sides.middle, Sides.left};

        order(list);
        System.out.print("Ordered: ");
        for (Sides side : list) {
            System.out.print(side.toString() + ", ");
        }
    }

    public static void order(Sides[] sides) {
        Sides[] possibleValues = Sides.values();

        int[] counts = new int[possibleValues.length];
        for (Sides side : sides) {
            counts[side.ordinal()]++;
        }

        int i=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < counts.length; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < counts[j]; k++)
                sides[i++] = possibleValues[j];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When you have a small, fixed range of values, you can use a [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) to sort them. The algorithm involves counting up the number of items of each type, then emitting that many of each item in order. For large numbers, where maintaining a count of each possible value would not be possible, this process can be repeated on each digit. For the special case where there is only one digit to count (as is the case here), the algorithm is also known as a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) (technically, a radix sort is a repeated application of counting sort on each of the various digits or buckets of the values being sorted).

To give you some code:

```
 enum Side {
    LEFT,
    MIDDLE,
    RIGHT
 }

 public static Side[] sort(Side[] sides) {
    Side[] values = Side.values();
    int valueCount = values.length;
    int[] counts = new int[valueCount];
    Arrays.fill(counts, 0);
    for (Side side : sides) {
       counts[side.ordinal()]++;
    }
    Side[] result = new Side[sides.length];
    int resultIndex = 0;
    for (int countIndex = 0; countIndex < counts.length; countIndex++) {
      int count = counts[countIndex];
      Side side = values[countIndex];
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        result[resultIndex] = side;
        resultIndex++;
      }
    }
    return result;
 }
```

**Edit history / notes**

In an earlier version, instead of using `ordinal()` and `values()` (methods automatically generated by Java, which I had previously been unaware of -- credit to Andreas@ for pointing these out), the code used a custom constructor and additional methods to implement such a lookup:

```
enum Side {
  LEFT,
  MIDDLE,
  RIGHT;

  private static int typeCount;
  private static Map<Integer, Side> valueToSide = new HashMap<>();
  private int value;

  private Side() {
    value = typeCount;
    valueToSide.put(value, this);
    typeCount++;
  }

  public static int getTypeCount() {
    return typeCount;
  }

  public static Side fromValue(int value) {
    return valueToSide.get(value);
  }

  public int intValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

This mechanism of writing custom constructors and adding methods to enum classes is handy in other scenarios but obviously should not be used to duplicate functionality that is already built in.

Comment: You can't access static members from an enum constructor.

Comment: You don't need any of that on the `Side` enum. `getTypeCount()` = `values().length`, `intValue()` = `ordinal()`, `fromValue(int)` = `values()[int]`

Comment: @Andreas cool, I didn't realize these were automatically generated.

Answer (score 0):

You want some n log(n) sorting algorithm. [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is probably the fastest. There's also a Java example implementation of Quicksort [here](http://java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/quick-sort/).

That said, it might be overkill for this question.

Comment: Arrays.sort() is an O(n log n) algorithm. As the OP stated, however, it is possible to achieve a faster sort in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

If the list is small (~20 elements or smaller), simply use [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). It will be faster than quick sort (although I believe merge sort is the standard sorting algorithm used in Java).

However this will require that you overload the less than operator. Since this is Java, you can just write a LessThan method instead.

Hope this helps!